# Ionic fails to build for IOS - Error code 65 for command

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic App that I am trying to build for IOS (for the first time). I keep getting this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/IHS_App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IHS_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/IonicKeyboard.o IHS_App/Plugins/com.ionic.keyboard/IonicKeyboard.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/dismac/Desktop/IHS/Software/trunk/app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,IHS_App.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,IHS_App,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/dismac/Desktop/IHS/Software/trunk/app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/dismac/Desktop/IHS/Software/trunk/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I have no idea where to start here? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the keyboard plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm com.ionic.keyboard
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Don't know why it worked